# VBA through Internet Explorer, Find String of Text and Use It

Tags: vba, excel, search

Within a page that I am able to open with VBA; I want to click on the first link in a table, then copy some data, close that window, click on the second link of the table, etc.

```
<a title="Open" 
  onmouseover="javascript:window.status='Click here!';return true;"
  onmouseout="javascript:window.status='';return true;" 
  onclick="OpenWindow(this.href, 'Profile_5193622', 760, 565); return false;" 
  href="/Pages/Popups/Profile.aspx?pid=5193622">
```

I want to use the "/Pages/Popups/Profile.aspx?pid=5193622" in a URL and navigate to it. How do I need to go about this?

You have to click a few places to get there. This will take you there:

```
Sub ExtractFirstLeagueData()


Dim IE As Object, obj As Object
Dim League As Object
Dim links, link
Dim dict As Object




Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate ("http://whatifsports.com/hbd/Pages/Main/WorldRedirect.aspx?id=3")

WaitFor IE

IE.navigate ("http://whatifsports.com/HBD/Pages/World/PlayerSearch.aspx")

WaitFor IE

IE.document.getelementsbyname("ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Main$PageOptionsPlaceHolder$PageOptionsPlaceHolder$lNameTextBox")(0).Value = "a"

IE.document.getelementsbyname("ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Main$PageOptionsPlaceHolder$PageOptionsPlaceHolder$LevelDropDown$LevelDropDown")(0).Value = "5"

IE.document.forms(0).submit

WaitFor IE

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

WaitFor IE

'collect the player links
Set links = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

WaitFor IE

For Each link In links
If link.href Like "*/Popups/PlayerProfile.aspx?pid=*" Then
    dict.Add link.innertext, link.href
End If
Next link

'navigate to each page and collect info
For Each link In dict.keys
IE.navigate dict(link)
WaitFor IE
Debug.Print IE.document.URL
'get player info here...
Next link
End Sub

Sub WaitFor(IE As Object)
While IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of going back to the table after loading each link, it would be easier to collect all of the links in an array or collection, and then loop over them and collect the data you need from each of the target pages.  If you need more specific help it would be best to edit your question to include your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim links, link
Dim dict As Object

'-------------------------
'get to the right page...
'-------------------------

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

'collect the player links
Set links = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each link In links
    If link.href Like "*/Popups/PlayerProfile.aspx?pid=*" Then
        dict.Add link.innerText, link.href
    End If
Next link

'navigate to each page and collect info
For Each link In dict.keys
    IE.navigate dict(link)
    WaitFor IE
    Debug.Print IE.document.URL
    'get player info here...
Next link
```

Helper sub:

```
Sub WaitFor(IE As Object)
    While IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: How long should this take to run? It seems like my macro is stuck searching for the links.

Comment: When i ran it it was pretty quick

Comment: I updated my post including your addition. My macro is not executing the "For each link in links" section. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Are the opened windows not visible? maybe?